# Abrir NavigationDrawer en HomeFragment que he creado en MainActivity con ImageView onClick

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity, navigationview

Quiero abrir NavigationDrawer que he creado en MainActivity en el HomeFragment utilizando ImageView onClick que tengo en mi HomeFragment. Ahora cuando le doy al ImageView la app se cierra y entiendo que es porque no tengo ningún drawerLayout en HomeFragment, pero no lo quiero allí. Quiero utilizar el DrawerLayout NavigationDrawer que he creado en MainActivity y abrirlo en HomeFragment dándole a un icono. Es posible hacerlo? Y si es posible qué es lo que tengo hacer porque lo he mirado todo y no sé si utilizar el getActivity(), no sé cómo hacerlo. Llevo demasiado con esta pregunta y no sé qué hacer.

Espero que alguien me vaya a poder aconsejar.

Abajo tenéis mi fragment_home.xml y HomeFragment.xml y el MainActivity.java también.

```
MainActivity.java

    package com.e.events;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
    import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
    import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

    import com.e.events.Fragment.HomeFragment;
    import com.e.events.Fragment.NotificationsFragment;
    import com.e.events.Fragment.ProfileFragment;
    import com.e.events.Fragment.SaveFragment;
    import com.e.events.Fragment.SearchFragment;
    import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
    import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DrawerLocker, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

        private DrawerLayout drawer;

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
        Fragment selectedFragment = null;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
                    R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

            bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navigationItemSelectedListener);

            Bundle intent = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (intent != null) {
                String publisher = intent.getString("publisherid");

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("profileid", publisher);
                editor.apply();

                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new ProfileFragment()).commit();
            } else {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new HomeFragment()).commit();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            int id = menuItem.getItemId();
            switch (id) {
                case R.id.nav_edit_profile:
                    Intent editProfile = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditProfileActivity.class);
                    startActivity(editProfile);
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_settings:
                    Intent settings = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(settings);
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_logout:
                    Intent logout = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class)
                            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
                    break;
            }

            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.nav_edit_profile) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigationItemSelectedListener =
                new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

                        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.nav_home:
                                selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                                break;
                            case R.id.nav_search:
                                selectedFragment = new SearchFragment();
                                break;
                            case R.id.nav_notifications:
                                selectedFragment = new NotificationsFragment();
                                break;
                            case R.id.nav_profile:
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                                editor.putString("profileid", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                                editor.apply();
                                selectedFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                                break;
                            case R.id.nav_save:
                                selectedFragment = new SaveFragment();
                                break;
                        }

                        if (selectedFragment != null) {
                            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                                    selectedFragment).commit();
                        }

                        return true;
                    }
                };
        public void setDrawerLocked(boolean enabled){
            if(enabled){
                drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
            }else{
                drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
            }

        }
    }
```

fragment_home.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".Fragment.HomeFragment">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_home_fragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
                    android:elevation="4dp"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/events_logo_main_activity"
                            android:layout_width="180dp"
                            android:layout_height="45dp"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/events_logo_black_max_size" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/camera_create_an_event_main_activity"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_camera_create_events_home_fragment_black" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/three_bars_settings_main_activity"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_three_bars_settings_home_fragment_black" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bar">

            </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_circular"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

```
HomeFragment.java

    package com.e.events.Fragment;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
    import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
    import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.e.events.Adapter.PostAdapter;
    import com.e.events.EditProfileActivity;
    import com.e.events.MainActivity;
    import com.e.events.Model.Post;
    import com.e.events.OptionsActivity;
    import com.e.events.PostActivity;
    import com.e.events.R;
    import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

        ImageView options;
        DrawerLayout drawer;

        ProgressBar progressBar;

        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private PostAdapter postAdapter;
        private List<Post> postLists;

        private ImageView camera_create_event;

        private List<String> followingList;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

            recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
            linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
            linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            postLists = new ArrayList<>();
            postAdapter = new PostAdapter(getContext(), postLists);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);

            progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progress_circular);

            drawer = view.findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

            Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_home_fragment);
            options = view.findViewById(R.id.three_bars_settings_main_activity);

            options.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
            });

            camera_create_event = view.findViewById(R.id.camera_create_an_event_main_activity);

            camera_create_event.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PostActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            checkFollowing();

            return view;
        }

        private void checkFollowing() {
            followingList = new ArrayList<>();

            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Follow")
                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                    .child("following");

            reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    followingList.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        followingList.add(snapshot.getKey());
                    }

                    readPosts();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }

        private void readPosts() {
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");

            reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    postLists.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                        for (String id : followingList) {
                            if (post.getPublisher().equals(id)) {
                                postLists.add(post);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Logcat

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.e.events, PID: 18229
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.e.events.Fragment.HomeFragment$1.onClick(HomeFragment.java:85)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6663)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6635)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:794)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26199)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)

Comment: Tienes el proyecto en github? Lo digo para poder compilarlo y verlo con detalle

Comment: @solamente No lo tengo en github, pero en principio estas tres páginas son las que utilizo HomeFragment.java, fragment_home.xml, MainActivity.java. No sabes si puedo abrir el NavView que tengo en MainActivity si en HomeFragment no tengo el drawerLayout? Seguro que se puede hacer, lo único es que no sé como. Si quieres subo el MainActivity

Comment: Si puedes sube todo el código y haré la prueba en mi ordenador

Comment: @solamente hecho, acabo de subir el MainActivity.java. A ver si me puedes ayudar, y la verdad es que he mirado por todas las páginas, vídeos y demás y no me doy con la respuesta. Gracias. Quiero abrir el NavigationView en HomeFragment, pero lo tengo en MainActivity. No lo quiero poner en el fragment_home.xml

Answer (score 0):

Este problema se debe a que el `DrawerLayout` con id `nav_view` no se encuentra en el layout `fragment_home.xml` que es usado por tu `Fragment`.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

       ...

        drawer = view.findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        ...
        ...

        options.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               //* La referencia no existe drawer es null
                drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });

       ....
    }
```

Asegura que el `DrawerLayout` se encuentre en `fragment_home.xml`

Comment: Si añado el DrawerLayout en el fragment_home.xml me va a funcionar aunque tenga el nav_view en el MainActivity? Porque no quiero el nav_view en el HomeFragment lo quiero en el MainActivity y poder utilizarlo desde allí si fuera posible... O tengo que crear un NavigationDrawer en HomeFragment también?